# how to serialize a form when there are multiple input fields (JSON)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I used to have 2 forms but after reading a few posts I realized that 2 forms did serve my purpose so I merge both forms under one unique form. I am using the user entries as query parameters to display 2 tables (i have 2 input fields and 2 corresponding buttons). I want entry1 to be a filter for query2. In my js file, I wrote 2 search functions using JSON format and AJAX. When I had 2 forms, I could populate both tables but I could not access input1 as a filter. Now that I merged the 2 forms into one form, I can access input1 BUT now I have an issue with the serialize function to pass the data from a specific input field from the merge form? How do I use the serialize() function so it applies only to one input field of the form? here the js file for search2 after button2 is clicked:

```
function runSearch2( term) {                                                  

$('#table2').empty();                                                     
$('#table1').empty();                                                     
//Alert ('go');                                                           
// transforms all the form parameters into a string we can send to the se$
var frmStr = $('#user_entry').serialize();                                

$.ajax({                                                                  
    url: './cgi_temp2.cgi',                                               
    dataType: 'json',                                                     
    data: frmStr,                                                         
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                          
        processJSON2(data);                                               
    },                                                                    
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                      
        alert("Failed to perform gene search! textStatus: (" + textStatus$
              ") and errorThrown: (" + errorThrown + ")");                
    }                                                                     
});
```

}

Comment: attach name attribute to all input elements, every element will be serialized using .serialize()

Comment: You know, [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) does not produce JSON. It produces 
a key=value pair URL encoded string

Comment: thank you. the JSON file is created after a mySQL query using a CGI script (my question was a bit misleading)

Answer (score -1):

This is easy.  you can just select entry1 to be serialized:

```
var frmStr = $('#entry1').serialize();
```

Provided that that entry1 has a id="entry1" attribute.
[Jquery Serialize reference](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: now that I merges the 2 forms and I am able to serialize each user input, i thought that it would allow me to access the value of input1 to use it as a filter for query2 in my cgi script.. but it looks like that i am not able to read the value of input1 and add it as a condition to my mysql query.. it is never easy!